# update data using setState when I passing to axios post request

Tags: reactjs, forms, axios, react-hooks

[image]I am passing data in form using urlParams in defaultValue i.e uncontrolled component after that whatever I am getting data I want to send to axios post request and user hits submit button all data store in database I am using hooks but I am getting empty data when I submit the button .I am facing difficult to update data into setState when I sending to post request below I have also attach codesandbox link and code. **https://codesandbox.io/live/fwesdvq**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import axios from "axios";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  useLocation,
} from "react-router-dom";
export default function Form(props) {
  const [sale, setSale] = useState("");
  const [district, setDistrict] = useState("21");
  const [billing, setBilling] = useState("");
  const [customer, setCustomer] = useState("");
  const [custgroup, setCustgroup] = useState("");
  const [product, setProduct] = useState("");
  

  var bodyFormData = new FormData();
  bodyFormData.append("sale", "12");

  bodyFormData.append("district", district);
  bodyFormData.append("billing", billing);
  bodyFormData.append("customer", customer);
  bodyFormData.append("product", product);
  bodyFormData.append("prodgroup", prodgroup);
 
  axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/form",

    data: { bodyFormData },
    headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      //handle success
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
      //handle error
      console.log(response);
    });
  
  const { search } = useLocation();

  const urlParams = Object.fromEntries([...new URLSearchParams(search)]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(urlParams);
  }, [urlParams]);

  const classes = useStyles();

  const [currency, setCurrency] = React.useState("EUR");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setCurrency(event.target.value);
  };
  
  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log("get", JSON.stringify(data));
  //console.log(url);
  return (
    <div>
      <Grid
        container
        container
        direction="column"
        alignItems="center"
        justify="center"
      >
        <Grid item xs={12} lg={6}>
          <Card
            className="p-4 mb-4"
            style={{
              height: 765,
              transform: "rotateX(15deg)",
            }}
          >
            <Container component="main" fixed>
              <CssBaseline />
              
                <div
                  className="heading"
                  style={{
                    marginTop: -73,
                    fontSize: 38,
                    marginRight: 15,
                    color: "#002699",
                  }}
                >
                  <h5>Action Tracker</h5>
                </div>
                <form
                  className={classes.form}
                  noValidate
                  onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}
                  //onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                >
                  <Grid container spacing={4}>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                      <TextField
                        type="text"
                        variant="outlined"
                        fullWidth
                        id="sales"
                        label="Sales office"
                        name="sale"
                        autoComplete="lname"
                        onChange={(event) => {
                          setSale(event.target.value);
                        }}
                        defaultValue={urlParams.salesoff}
                      />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                      <TextField
                        type="text"
                        variant="outlined"
                        fullWidth
                        id="billing"
                        label="Billing document"
                        name="billing"
                        autoComplete="lname"
                        onChange={(event) => {
                          setBilling(event.target.value);
                        }}
                        defaultValue={urlParams.billingdoc}
                      />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        type="text"
                        fullWidth
                        id="district"
                        label="Sales district"
                        name="district"
                        autoComplete="lname"
                        onChange={(event) => {
                          setDistrict(event.target.value);
                        }}
                        defaultValue={urlParams.salesdist}
                      />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        type="number"
                        fullWidth
                        id="sold"
                        label="Quantity sold"
                        name="sold"
                        onChange={(event) => {
                          setQty(event.target.value);
                        }}
                        defaultValue={urlParams.qtysold}
                      />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        fullWidth
                        id="customer-name"
                        label="Customer name"
                        name="customer-name"
                        autoComplete="lname"
                        onChange={(event) => {
                          setCustomer(event.target.value);
                        }}
                        defaultValue={urlParams.custname}
                      />
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        type="number"
                        fullWidth
                        id="target"
                        label="Target price"
                        name="target"
                        autoComplete="lname"
                        onChange={(event) => {
                          setTarget(event.target.value);
                        }}
                        defaultValue={urlParams.targetprice}
                      />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        type="text"
                        fullWidth
                        id="name"
                        label="Product name"
                        name="product-name"
                        autoComplete="lname"
                        onChange={(event) => {
                          setProduct(event.target.value);
                        }}
                        defaultValue={urlParams.product}
                      />
                    </Grid>
                   
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                      <TextField
                        fullWidth
                        id="outlined-select-currency"
                        select
                        label={
                          <Typography style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>
                            Action expected
                          </Typography>
                        }
                        value={currency}
                        variant="outlined"
                      >
                        {actions.map((option) => (
                          <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                            {option.label}
                          </MenuItem>
                        ))}
                      </TextField>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        type="number"
                        fullWidth
                        id="lastName"
                        label="Price increment"
                        name="lastName"
                        autoComplete="lname"
                      />
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                  <Button
                    type="submit"
                    fullWidth
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    className={classes.submit}
                    onClick={Form}
                  >
                    Submit
                  </Button>
                  <Grid container justify="flex-end">
                    <Grid item></Grid>
                  </Grid>
                </form>
              </div>
            </Container>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what your actual question is. Is it about updating state from uncontroleld inputs? Gathering the state for form data submission? Getting the form values from the form's `onSubmit` event object? Can you clarify what you are needing help with? Your axios call is in the function body so it's made as a side-effect any time the component renders.

Comment: @DrewReese updating state from uncontrolled input i.e getting the value from defaultValue I want to update state for form data submission

Comment: Your inputs have `onChange` handlers so I would think your state is updating. Is this an issue, state *not* updating as you expect?

Comment: yes state is not updating whatever I am gettimg data through urlParams the only thing is generated in databse is id created and updated but data is empty my main motive is when user click submit all the data stored in databse in backend everything is undefined I am getting  @Drew Reese

Comment: I forked your sandbox and log state updates in an `useEffect` hook and see state updating as I would expect. I guess your issue is still unclear to me. What are you trying to do? Can you walk us through the steps for what you doing?

Comment: Yes so I am fecthing data through urlParams so every inputtextfield is filled up with default value and after that when user click submit button all the data should store in database and I am connecting axios post request url through my backend I am attaching nodejs image how I am posting data in backend . @Drew Reese